# SQL query to retrieve primary key column from a table which is stored in multiple databases

Tags: mysql

I am working on a project related to a database. I want to find out the highest value from the primary key column of a same table (say tbrmenuitem) which is stored in multiple databases.

So, is it possible through one query or I do have to fire a different query at different times to make the connection with multiple databases? (that is, the first query to get the table name in the database, the second query to find the primary key of the table I got and then MAX() on the value of the primary key column?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can query tables in other databases on a server similar to how you would any other tables. You just need to qualify the table name with the name of the schema (database).

```
SELECT MAX(max) FROM (
    SELECT MAX(id_column) AS max
        FROM test2.test2table
    UNION ALL
    SELECT MAX(id_column) AS max
        FROM test.test1table
) AS t
```

What this does, is selects the `MAX()` of a column from the table `test2table` in the `test2` database.

```
SELECT MAX(id_column) AS max
  FROM test2.test2table
```

It then performs a UNION on that result, with the result of a similar query performed on the `test1table` table in the `test` database.

```
UNION ALL
SELECT MAX(id_column) AS max
  FROM test.test1table
```

This is then wrapped in a subquery which pulls the maximum value of each of the results returned from the UNION.

Comment: What if databases are on different physical machines?

Comment: You can use federated tables for this. (Shameless plug) see [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23822678/copy-a-table-with-data-from-one-mysql-server-to-another/23822887#23822887) for explanation of how they work. Fairly straight forward.