# Copy a table with data from one MySQL server to another

Tags: mysql, copy

I have a MySQL DB on a computer, and the same MySQL DB on a different server. I need them to be exactly the same in term of structure and contained data and I've come to the point where the only way I can do that is by truncating one table and then inserting into it all the rows of the other (exactly the same) table.

I want this to happen through a MySQL query and not by making backups and then importing it, not by database migrations or such, but by a query, because I plan using this query in a VB project and use it whenever there is a change in any of the two tables.

I know that if the tables where on the same server the query would have been as follows:

```
INSERT INTO db.table1 SELECT * FROM db.table2
```

But I don't know how to write the `SELECT` clause and how to tell it that .table2 is on another server.

I think it should be something like this

```
INSERT INTO db.table1 SELECT * FROM (ServerName/IP).db.table2
```

But can't quite figure it out by myself, any ideas?

Comment: The table that i'll be getting the values which i insert into the empty table is from the server

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can setup [federated tables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/federated-use.html), which is basically linking a table on one server to a table on another. Then use the federation to do your data transfers.

> First, you must have a table on the remote server that you want to access by using a FEDERATED table. Suppose that the remote table is in the federated database and is defined like this:

```
CREATE TABLE test_table (
    id     INT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name   VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    other  INT(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY  (id),
    INDEX name (name),
    INDEX other_key (other)
)
ENGINE=MyISAM
DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

> Next, create a FEDERATED table on the local server for accessing the remote table:

```
CREATE TABLE federated_table (
    id     INT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name   VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    other  INT(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY  (id),
    INDEX name (name),
    INDEX other_key (other)
)
ENGINE=FEDERATED
DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
CONNECTION='mysql://fed_user@remote_host:9306/federated/test_table';
```

Then you can query it like any other table.

There are however a decent number of [limitations you should read about](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/federated-usagenotes.html) including the remote password being stored in plain text. If this was a temporary setup purely for a once off copy, and the server isn't available to the public you have already minimised most of the risk associated with it though.